# How to schedule an alarm on specific time in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager

In my Flutter project, I want to schedule an alarm on a specific time of a day or just trigger the built in alarm in my phone on that particular time.

For that purpose, I have integrated one plugin from Flutter -

https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager#-example-tab-

And then I followed exactly the example given in that documentation and added all the permissions in Android Manifest file.

After running this project it shows like below-

[image]

It is showing one button to shot one alarm but it is just updating the text. Nothing like any alarm is set as I wanted and I am not getting what's going on in this project.

So, I need a solution that- what changes I need to do get that alarm working on a fixed time scheduled by me and it should work from background as I want this alarm to work when I remove it from memory too.
Any example code sample, full documentation or project sample will be helpful for this question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use some things together. You need to run a background process and start to play a sound from there.
I suggest you to take a deep look at the flutter docs about the subject:

 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

Here are some useful packages that might help:

- To run background processes continuously, take a look at this package: 
   https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch
- To play a sound from background processes:

   https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes
- If you need to show scheduled messages, use local notifications:

   https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: Hello @Rod, thanks for your help. I would like to ask you a small question if you mind.

Why do I need to play sound from the background processes? It's not enough to use the background process package to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AhmadAlmosallam. The background process only runs while the app is open. It's a parallel processing called Isolated, but it can run independently of the application. The background_fetch allows the app to run some scheduled dart code. You need both of them: one will schedule the code to run when the app is closed, the other will effectively do what you want (play the sound).

Comment: Thank you @Rod for your response. Okay, I do understand what you are saying.
Let us look to another case, Let's say that I have to send notifications 5 times each day, And to schedule these notifications, a function that calculates the time for each one notification to fire, this function runs at the end of the day 12:00AM.

Comment: @AhmadAlmosallam You need to use background_fetch to schedule the "scheduler" function. The "scheduler" fuction needs to run a background process to schedule 5 notifications. But there is another solution to your problem. Android and IOS handle scheduled processes in a different way from each other and both of them have ways of doing daily schedules (like daily alarms). You should take a look at the docs.